# List outcomes in loops- gmapsdistance

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am trying to use the R package *gmapsdistance* to calculate the road distance and travel time between two sets of co-ordinates. I have created the following loop as I have 2524 routes to calculate.

```
for(i in 1:2524) {
df$Distance_Time[i] <- as.data.frame(gmapsdistance
                              (origin = c(df$OriginCo[i]), 
                              destination = c(df$DestinationCo[i]), 
                              combinations = "pairwise", 
                              mode = "driving",
                              shape = "long",
                              set.api.key("MY_API_KEY"))) 
}
```

An example of my df is as follow;

OriginCo : chr "-39.9+174.99", "-40.27+175.55", "-39.66+176.77"...

DestinationCo : chr "-40.27+175.55", "-39.9+174.99", "-40.27+175.55"...

Distance_Time :

However, because the output of *gmapdistance* is a list, the new column in the df (Distance_time) only shows the travel time for each set of co-ordinates.

If I run the code on the first set of co-ordinates, instead of a loop, I get  $time, $distance and $status.

How can I make another column to show distance and status or have these two variables listed along with the $time?

Many thank in advance

Comment: This is not a reproducible question.  Please use the function `dput` to post a sample of your data.

Comment: I've edited the question, I hope this makes it slightly clearer, thank you @Dave2e